# Unpivot dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Original dataframe:

```
d=DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2),columns=['price','#sold'],index=['A','B','C'])


   price #sold
A   0    1
B   2    3
C   4    5
```

Desired output:

```
   price
A   0   
B   2    
B   2    
B   2    
C   4
C   4
C   4
C   4
C   4
```

How to 'unpivot' the dataframe, such that the row will repeat x times (where x = # sold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
In [76]: pd.DataFrame({'price':np.repeat(d['price'].values, d['#sold'])})
Out[76]: 
   price
0      0
1      2
2      2
3      2
4      4
5      4
6      4
7      4
8      4
```